# Logging to Stackdriver from a web application

Tags: logging, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-cloud-logging

I would like to log an info message to Google Stackdriver from a web app without the user having to sign in. Is it possible? I am using gapi from Google.

gapi.load('client:auth', start);

then => gapi.client.init({ apiKey, discoveryDocs, client_id, scope});

then => gapi.auth2.authorize(...)

then => gapi.client.logging.entries.write(...);

=> PERMISSION DENIED**

Everything I try requires the user to sign in. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Sign In For websites, is mandatory authenticate a [google account](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), this is because the users must authorize the use of some scopes on the Google Login Screen before use the API.

To write logs from an application (with backend) to a stackdriver service is by creating a service account and using [stackdriver logging package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging)

You could find all information and steps to create and download your service account credentials in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).

Also in the same guide are explained how to use the package and call the credential in a node.JS code and in other programming languages.

When you have downloaded your service account credentials is necessary to save the path of the json file in the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" ENV variable using this command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Comment: Thank you answering! Would your suggestion with a node.js logging package also work in a Angular 8 web app hosted at google firebase?

Comment: if your backend is node.js this will work without defining any environment variables since applications in firebase/GCP already have the variables configured

Comment: The backend isn't built with node.js. I wonder if I can use the package anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, according the docs stackdriver only works with some backend languages such as Node.JS, php, python, etc..

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/